# Is there an ion capacitor event that is triggered when the app closes/unloads?

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm new with Ionic Capacitor, and I need one way to delete some cookies when the app is closed intencionally by the user, or is closed whitout the user intervention(for example when the app crashes or is closed by the OS). So my question is there is a listener on Ionic Capacitor that catch the events mentioned?

Comment: Hello, have you tried to clean the cookies on ngOnDestroy ?

Comment: If a crash happens, then how can additional post-logic occur? Perhaps, instead, you should analyze cookies on next boot of the app, and in early lifecycle stage, determine whether they should be cleared/modified/etc. Use date-time as a starting point, and just get more sophisticated if you need to, e.g. some kind of unique session id's, or whatever.